# SilverLight multi file uploader + Azure Blob storage : occasional corrupt uploads in IE

Tags: silverlight, file-upload, azure, blob, azure-storage

I am using [Silverlight multi file uploader](http://www.michielpost.nl/Silverlight/MultiFileUploader/) and Uploading the document in Azure Blob as Byte Array.

```
//Append the memory stream into ByteArray
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     stream.CopyTo(ms);
     return ms.ToArray();
 }

// Upload the file
blob.UploadByteArray(bytes);
```

Upload document appears to be corrupt **Intermittently**.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Network hicups occur.  You should run a content hash on both sides and if they do not match, let the user know and give option to download again.

Comment: @Steve How can we achieve content hash in javascripts side in Silverlight multi file uploader

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Azure Storage Client Library protects the integrity of the blob being uploaded by verifying an MD5 hash of the data when it is sent to the Windows Azure Storage Service (in most cases). If you are using an HTTPS connection to the service, this would also verify the data was sent without errors.

The details of how MD5 hashes are used: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/18/windows-azure-blob-md5-overview.aspx

I believe the corruption you are seeing occurred between the client's web browser and your application. You will need to have the user try their upload again.

By the way, your code creates two additional copies of the data unnecessarily (MemoryStream and byte array). Instead, try this:

```
blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
```

Comment: Solutions implemented : 
1. For checking the pdf corrupt between the user and the webserver : Read the uploaded pdf using iTextsharp.
2. For checking the pdf corrupt between webserver and Azure Blob storage : Doing a MD5CheckSum between webserver and pdf uploaded into azure
Result : 
The file is getting corrupt when its uploaded into webserver.The problem is between the user and the webserver. 

Any suggestion

Comment: @Padmalochan I think the best would be to show an error message to the user and ask them to try their upload again. This assumes you can detect that the upload failed. There is probably a direct way to know this. Otherwise, reading the file seems like a good solution. Plus this catches bad files the user is trying to upload.

Comment: this happens Intermittently, User are able to upload same document(Good Files) after few retry. We want to know the exact reason for document getting corrupt,Is it the uploader is missing a chunk while sending the document.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem? If so, you can find the answer to this question using a network monitoring tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark. These allow you to see the raw data being sent over the network.